# Как спарсить данные с сайта

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

Есть **сайт: https://hidemy.name/ru/proxy-list/**
И **код**(который просто скачивает страницу):

```
import requests


user_agent_val = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36'
}

r = requests.get('https://hidemy.name/ru/proxy-list/', headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)

with open("pr.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(r.text)

f.close()
with open("pr.html", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    contents = f.read()
```

Нужно спарсить все ip и порты со страницы(

```
<tr><td>158.58.197.227</td><td>50128</td><td><i class="flag-icon flag-icon-bg"></i> <span class="country">Bulgaria</span> <span class="city">Berkovitsa Municipality</span></td><td><div class="bar" style="color:#000"><p>480 мс</p><div class="speed" style="width:76px;background:#79bc00"></div></div></td><td>SOCKS4</td><td>Высокая</td><td>2 минуты</td></tr>
```

)
Почитал документалки но так и не понял как это сделать
*Заранее спасибо*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот программа, выводящая все айпи и порты со страницы:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36'
}

r = requests.get('https://hidemy.name/ru/proxy-list/', headers=headers)

raw = r.text.split('tbody>')[1].split('</tbody')[0] # "сырой" контент таблицы с адресами

arr = raw.split("<td>")

for i in range(0, len(arr) - 2, 7):
    print(arr[i+1][:-5], arr[i+2][:-5])
```

Answer (score 2):

1 Регулярные выражения. Если это уместно.

```
>>> e = re.search(r"<tr><td>([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})</td><td>([0-9]{2,5})</td><td>", """<tr><td>158.58.197.227</td><td>50128</td><td><i class="flag-icon flag-icon-bg"></i> <span class="country">Bulgaria</span> <span class="city">Berkovitsa Municipality</span></td><td><div class="bar" style="color:#000"><p>480 мс</p><div class="speed" style="width:76px;background:#79bc00"></div></div></td><td>SOCKS4</td><td>Высокая</td><td>2 минуты</td></tr>""")
>>> e.groups()
('158.58.197.227', '50128')
>>>
```

2 BeautifulSoup